# Are all integers a norm of an element of either $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ and $Z[\sqrt{3}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that the norm of an element $x+y\sqrt{b}$ for integers $x$, $y$, and $b$ is $N(x+y\sqrt{b}) = x^2 - by^2$.

My question is whether or not the union of the set of all integers such that they are expressable as a norm of an element of $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ and the set of all integers such that they are expressable as the norm of an element of $Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is the entire set of the integers. What if we consider only absolute values?

Are there any collections of these similar rings such their norms all form the service of the integers? I'm curious on whether this might serve as a way of expressing numbers in various forms for inductive proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $11$? Odd norms from $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ are $\pm1\pmod 8$
and norms coprime to $3$ from $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ are $1\pmod 3$.

This argument extends
to show that that no finite set of norms from quadratic rings
covers $\Bbb Z$.